# Initializing a vector of string_view the wrong way?

Tags: c++, string, vector, view, c++17

Bonjour,

Could please tell me why the first 3 lines do not work while the last 3 ones work?

See : https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/qozEsc

```
#include <vector>
#include <string_view>
#include <iostream>

int main(){

    const std::vector<std::string> W = {"aaa", "bbbb", "ccccc"};
    
    std::vector<std::string_view> Wbak1;
    for (std::string w : W) Wbak1.push_back(w.c_str());
    for(auto w:Wbak1) std::cout << w << '\n';

    std::vector<std::string_view> Wbak2;
    for (auto i = 0U; i < W.size(); ++i) Wbak2.push_back(W[i].c_str());
    for(auto w:Wbak2) std::cout << w << '\n';
}
```

Best regards, 40tude

Answer (score 7):

In the 1st range-based for loop, `w` is a *copy* of the element of `W`. After each loop iteration, `w` is destroyed, leaving the `w.c_str()` pointer held by `std::string_view` dangling.

You should declare `w` as a reference. e.g.

```
for (const std::string& w : W) Wbak1.push_back(w.c_str());
```

Comment: @40tude You're welcome. :) This is the [note of `std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view#Notes) that we have to pay attention to the lifetime of the pointed-to character array.

Comment: @40tude • these things can be subtle.  Even the C++ experts I work with get tripped up from time to time.